# Шляпа из будущего

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, новогодние-шляпы

Сейчас неожиданно получил новую шляпу, решил посмотреть что за шляпа и за что она.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все круто, но сегодня же 29 декабря.
Отговорки про часовые пояса не катят, т.к. четко указано, что шляпа заработана на *ru.stackoverflow.com*

Бажина.

Comment: Во Владивостоке уже за полночь.

Comment: @Nofate cервера находятся во Владивостоке? Я нахожусь во Владивостоке?)

Comment: При чем тут вы и сервера? Шляпа с солнцестоянием тоже срабатывала, когда оно начиналось где угодно в мире.

Comment: Что значит при чем тут я? Я четко у себя на машине вижу дату 29 декабря, я так же четко вижу в описании шляпы дату 30 декабря. Не соответствие заявленного с действительным является багом

Comment: Тоже есть такая шляпа. Я нахожусь в MSK, тут ещё полночь как во Владивостоке ещё не наступила. Присоединяюсь к вопросу: где должна наступить полночь? Даже если сервер находится в UTC - то и там ещё не наступило: https://yandex.ru/time

Comment: НА самом деле ответ вот http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288735/got-b%C3%BBche-de-no%C3%ABl-hat-on-dec-24-instead-of-have-a-little-dreidel

Comment: @AK следующий день наступает уже в 14.00 по МСК, на сколько я заметил.....вот поищите где по UTC уже полночь) а вообще ответ в ссылке выше, насколько я понял

Answer (score 7):

Похоже, что временные условия для шляп начинают срабатывать, когда в первом часовом поясе настаёт нужная дата и перестают, когда эта дата проходит в последнем часовом поясе.

Вижу три аргумента за такое решение:

- Упрощение логики. С учётом существования VPN, нельзя определять часовой пояс по IP входящего соединения. Аналогично, не у всех в профиле указан город.

  > Отговорки про часовые пояса не катят, т.к. четко указано, что шляпа заработана на ru.stackoverflow.com

  Часовой пояс не определяется по сайту. У нас есть участники из самых разных стран и со всех континентов.
- Честное соревнование. Нечестно, если кто-то вырвется вперёд только потому, что живёт в Японии.
- Предотвращение утечки информации. Если шляпы начнут выдаваться ровно в вашу локальную полночь, можно будет отследить это событие и определить ваш часовой пояс.

Comment: Получается, что сутки растягиваются таким образом до 48 часов. Странно всё это, особенно учитывая, что все остальные времена опираются тут на UTC (насколько я знаю).

Answer (score 5):

[Ответ на Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/339911):

> ### Leeway on date-based hats
>
> Unless the requirement mentions a specific timezone, hats that are date-based are often awarded for 14 hours before and 12 hours after the specified date in UTC, to accommodate people everywhere in the world. This means you can earn such a hat even though for you it's not even that day yet.
>
> > **Example:** The hat *Living in a Box* is awarded for voting to close a question on [December 26th](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_Day). To earn this hat, you have to cast a close vote between 12/25 at 10:00 UTC and 12/27 at 12:00 UTC.

Т.о. сутки растягиваются аж до 50 часов. Т.к. временной интервал начинается за 14 часов до упомянутой даты по UTC, а заканчиваются через 12 часов после окончания даты по UTC.

```
14 + 24 + 12 = 50 часов
```

Comment: Я так и знал, что на самом деле мы не на Земле, а на другой планете, а всё это — лишь эксперимент над остатком выживших людей, которые по наивности думают и живут 24 часа в сутки. А это лишь искусственные условия экспериментаторов